# Why is my jQuery code not working on dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below works if the #client-result-0 id is set to a static element. But when I point it to a dynamically created element, it doesn't work. I am using jQuery 1.7.1.

```
$j('#client-result-0') .on('click','.myLi',function(){
    console.log('haha');
    $j('#client-search-0').val($(this).text());
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Event is delegated to a static element, Since `#client-result-0` is dynamically generate it will not work. As you are aware set to a static element

Comment: No, #client-result-0 is the static element. #client-result-1 and so on would be the dynamic elements.

Comment: The element you delegate to has to exist when the event is bound, commonly on page load. Hence if you create `#client-result-0` *after* page load then no event is bound. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information